# Why is my Grafana template variable only showing 'None' instead of distinct values from my KQL query in Azure Log Analytics?

Tags: grafana, kql, azure-log-analytics

At the moment I'm struggling regarding (at least for me) an easy requirement for using Grafana template variables: "Show distinct values from a KQL Query as panel on the Dashboard".

Example: Give me all distinct Azure Data Factory Pipelines based on our Log Analytics Workspace:

```
ADFPipelineRun
| distinct PipelineName
```

My expectation is/was that the Variable is showing me all the PipelineNames which I then can use for filter my other Queries. Unfortunately it is only showing "None".

When I set up this query as a panel on the dashboard it is working like expected.

Am I missing something? I'm not new to KQL but to Grafana template variables.

Also tried to project it but it does not change the output.